# PHP 5.6 odbc_exec windows fatal error: Allowed memory size

Tags: php, memory, odbc, fatal-error

I'm under Win2008R2 and using odbc 32bit.
By switching from PHP 5.5.14 to 5.6.4 many simple queries now hangs with:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate ... **MORE THEN 1GB** ...)

Some of the queries are very simple and should load just some record or sometimes NULL.

I've read in other posts that if some field of the returned records are NULL this could lead to errors, but I can't solve by correcting the queries, these are thousands in a very big non standard enviroment!!

Comment: It is a known issues, however it mostly happens on 64bit systems, it's said that it has been fixed https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=50444
But i also have the same problem on Linux 64bit PHP 5.6.5 which is strange. Compiling php from source may help but haven't tried it yet

Answer (score 0):

For Windows there is a bug report, have a look
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68964